# Notepad++ RegEx

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am in need a reg ex for the following:

```
/****** Object: AnyNumberofCharacters ******/
```

Here is what I have Tried but I cant make it work

```
/^\/\*\*\*\*\*\* Object\:.*\*\*\*\*\*\*\//
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edited:**  Sorry I'm using NotePad++ to search a number of text files for this string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Notepad++ to find that string, you don't need the delimiters. And therefore, you don't need to escape the forward slashes either.

```
^/\*\*\*\*\*\* Object\:.*\*\*\*\*\*\*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that

```
/^\/\*{6} Object: [\w]+ \*{6}\/$/
```

should do that...

Don't forget to adjust the [\w] range accordingly.

Comment: Just beat me to it.  Might want to add \s+? before/after your line/word boundaries though.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the existing regex, I tested it with the delimiters in JS `RegExp` and it works fine. Not saying that this wouldn't work though, of course :)

Comment: Yeah, it should work, seemed fine to me... But this works for real :]

Comment: For those watching at home, the `/` characters at the beginning and end of the regex suggested here are delimiters for the regex. They delimit the regex in javascript (and maybe PHP, not sure). The actual regex is what appears between those two slashes. In a .NET language you would use double-quotes as delimiters, because regex are just strings.  So, in .NET, write `"^\/\*{6} Object: [\w]+ \*{6}\/$"`.